# phpDocumentor installation fails in laravel using composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, documentation-generation, phpdocumentor2

I am trying to install phpdocumentor using composer by doing `composer require phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor` in a laravel 5.3 project for generating documentation. I am using a linux machine with ubuntu16.04 and my php version is 7.0. I am getting the following error

```
- Can only install one of: symfony/translation[v2.5.5, v3.1.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/translation[v2.5.6, v3.1.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/translation[v2.5.7, v3.1.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/translation[v2.5.8, v3.1.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/translation[v2.5.9, v3.1.10].

Installation request for symfony/translation (locked at v3.1.10) -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[v3.1.10].
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Problem is that laravel requires symfony/translation version upwards of 3.1 i.e. `^3.1.*` but phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor supports symfony/translation only until 2.8.9.

So what can I do if I want to install phpdocumentor along-with laravel5.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no way to install phpdocumentor alongwith laravel using composer. I tried installing php7.0-xsl and tried doing a number of hacks like deleting the composer.lock file and then doing composer install etc to no avail. I could finally get it to work using `pear`. Precisely doing

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org 
sudo pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor
```

For more info refer [here](https://docs.phpdoc.org/getting-started/installing.html#using-pear%20'here'')

Comment: When I tried this method of installing it inside a docker container I got. "Discovering channel pear.phpdoc.org over http:// failed with message: channel-add: Cannot open "http://pear.phpdoc.org/channel.xml" (File http://pear.phpdoc.org:80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
))
Trying to discover channel pear.phpdoc.org over https:// instead
Error: Unable to create XML parser
Discovery of channel "pear.phpdoc.org" failed (channel-add: invalid channel.xml file)"

Comment: It worked for laravel5.3 and php7.0 on ubuntu 16.04. Can't say the same about other versions. Also pear may change its repositories and links.

Comment: I was able to get it installed by adding the following to my dockerfile # Install phpDocumentor with Pear
RUN wget https://pear.phpdoc.org/channel.xml \
    && pear channel-add ./channel.xml
RUN wget https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/releases/download/v2.9.0/phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz \
    && pear install phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache restart
```

worked for me on Linux ubuntu 16.04 to intall XSL.